# How to delete from the cursor to the end of a parenthetical expression in Vim?

Tags: vim, editor, motion

Say I have this line of text in Vim:

```
(foo bar (baz) qux)
    ^
```

and my cursor is on the space between the words `foo` and `bar`, as indicated. I often find that, in situations like this, I want to delete the entire right-hand side of the outer parenthesized expression (that is, to the right of my cursor), while leaving the left-hand side intact. That is, I'd like to end up with:

```
(foo)
```

Usually, I’d accomplish this with `dt)` (“delete until `)`”), but the addition of a nested parenthetical complicates things: That command would leave me with `(foo) qux)`. I could also use `d2t)`, but I’d prefer not to have to manually count the number of nested parentheses. I could also use `di)`, but that deletes the *entire* text inside of the parentheses, leaving me with `()`.

Is there a Vim motion with the balance-awareness of the [`i`- and `a`-modified motions](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#aw) that is also relative to the current cursor position?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `])` motion with `d`.

```
d])
```

Comment: I didn't know about `])`; that's certainly simpler than my solution (but mine should still work for non-vim versions of vi).

Comment: @Keith Thompson: Your solution is certainly vi compatible which is nice. My fear w/ your solution is that it is dependent on `F(` finding the appropriate `(` to jump to. I think I would prefer to do `df)` and repeat w/ `.` and then `a)`. Or `mxF(` then repeat `F` motion with `,` until the correct `(` is found then ``%d`x``

Comment: Yeah, I just thought of a case where my solution won't work: `( (before) foo ^ (after) )`.  The `F(` or `?(<return>` will find the left paren preceding `before`, not the nearest one enclosing the cursor position.  (I remember a `:set lisp` command from many years ago.  I see vim still has it.  What does it do?  Yeah, I should RTFM.)

Comment: @Keith Thompson: `set lisp` will change some indenting rules and allow`-` as part of a keyword.

Answer (score 3):

```
mxF(%d`x
```

Breaking it down:

```
mx
```

Set a mark `x` (pick whatever letter you like)

```
F(
```

Find previous `(` character

```
%
```

Jump to matching `)`

```
d`x
```

Delete from here to mark `x`

That works for your specific case; I'm not sure how general it is.  If the previous `(` is not on the current line, use `?(<return>` rather than `F(`.

**EDIT**:
I didn't mention `d])` because I didn't know about it.

My solution won't work for this case:

```
( (before) foo (after) )
              ^
```

because it jumps back to the nearest `(`, not the nearest *enclosing* `(`.